# Submit dynamic checkbox values via PHP & AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I submit checked values via ajax to a separate page? My code is as follows:

```js
function genereted(){
var selctednom = new Array();
$("input:checked").each(function() {
   data['selctednom'].push($(this).val());
});
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "bar.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { selctednom:selctednom },
            success: function(data){
                alert('ok')
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<td><input id="selctednom"type="checkbox" value="<?php echo trim($row['test']);?>" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the id should be unique. Add name to inputs.
You can serialize your form -  only checked checkboxes will be send.

```
 <td><input name='selctednom[]' type="checkbox" value="<?php echo trim($row['test']);?>" /></td>


$('form').submit(function() {    
         $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "bar.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:  $("form").serialize(), 
                    success: function(data){
                        alert('ok')
                    }
                });
            }
         return false;
    });
```

Comment: I'd go as far and say that the `id` MUST be unique.